# BSOD on windows server 2008 R2 reason Srv2.sys Driver_IRQL_not_Less_or_Equal

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, bsod

I have a issue that i have been facing with my windows server 2008 R2 (ADC Server) Additional Domain Controller (Roles Installed AD,DNS).

It suddenly gives a BSOD i did analyse the dump and found out the case of a driver that is Srv2.sys with a bug check string (DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL).

Caused By Driver : Srv2.sys

Caused By Address : Srv2.sys+1467c

i do have a mini dump too

Require some fix on it as i searched on google i came up with a hot fix but dunno if it is reliable.

If the Thread is already created kindly move this to that group or address a link to me.

Comment: `1.` Please learn and use the correct terminology. There is no such things as an ADC. There are no Additional, Secondary or Backup DC's. There are just DC's. `2.` If you found a Microsoft hotfix relevant to the issue and the OS, why would you think it was unreliable? Install the hotfix. That is your solution.

Comment: sorry for that but could you provide me the link cuz i lost my bookmarks that has the link.

Comment: ADC is used in some courseware I've seen it before (although I don't disagree that it's redundant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular bug check - `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` - is caused when code, usually kernel-mode code, usually a device driver, attempts to access a paged, pageable, or invalid memory address at an Interrupt Request Level (IRQL) that is too high. This is usually because some device driver raised it, and doesn't put it back where it found it once it was done.  This is pretty much *always* a software bug in the device driver (though it may appear to occur in other modules that interact with that device driver,) and the only fix for it is to update the faulty code by installing a patch or new driver version. There are of course exceptions to this scenario but we wouldn't know without a thorough debugging of the machine.

Good references: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/doronh/archive/2010/02/02/what-is-irql.aspx

And *Windows Internals 6th Edition* by Mark Russinovich, et al.